# Harry Potter fanfic: Draco kidnaps Ginny and makes her act as his wife to fool Voldemort

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a specific harry potter fanfic I read a couple years ago. It involves Ginny Weasley and Draco Malfoy as the main pairing. I don't remember much about it since it's been years. What I do remember is that Ginny gets abducted by Draco in order to have her take care of his baby. There is also a part in which Draco makes Ginny drink a potion that changes her hips so it looks as if she was the one who gave birth to his child. They do this in order to fool Voldemort into thinking that she is Draco's wife and the mother of his child. Help me find this fanfic please!

Comment: *Lies*, maybe? That's a rather adult Draco/Ginny kidnap fic (though I cringe at using a slash for kidnap pairings).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I looked it up and unfortunately it wasn't the correct title. I just remembered, in the story both Draco and Ginny lie to Voldemort and act as husband and wife. As mentioned before she also acts as if she were the biological mother of Draco's baby.

Comment: Can you remember anything else? It looks like there are a lot of fanfictions where Draco kidnaps Ginny. Even a trivial detail could help, especially if it is google-able. If Draco's baby has an odd name, for example, that might be helpful.

Comment: Not really, I think it starts off with Ginny running some errand for her mom when she then gets kidnapped. She ends up in some small hiding place and she hears a baby crying. Turns out it is Draco's son, and he wants her to take care of him and act as his mother. I've been typing so much crap into google and I just can't find it.

Comment: Is that [tag:drinny]?

Answer (score 3):

It is called [*The devil you know by CCC on Dracoandginny.com*](http://www.dracoandginny.com/viewstory.php?sid=5710&warning=2).

> A loud pop frightened her out of her thoughts. She turned around and
>   saw a dark robed figure. He just stared at her as she clutched the
>   baby to her chest. “Please, let me go. I’ll take him with me. I’ll
>   take good care of him.”
>
> The man reached up and slowly removed his mask. Ginny expected to see
>   the cruel smirk she remembered from years ago. The cold, emotionless
>   face she saw was much more frightening. His eyes were empty of all
>   emotion, and he seemed to radiate cold composure.
>
> When he stepped towards her, she pulled the baby out of his reach.
>   Annoyance flickered across his features, before his face settled back
>   into an icy mask.
>
> His words were sharp. “If I wanted to harm him, I could have left him
>   to die. Give him to me.”
>
> Ginny realized his words were true. She held the baby out to him, and
>   watched as he awkwardly held the baby with one arm. He turned and
>   walked away from her, speaking quietly to the child.
>
> She watched the wand in his right hand, wondering if she should try
>   and make a grab for it.
>
> Inching forward, she was startled when he said, “How old do you think
>   he is?”
>
> “You don’t know?” she asked. He didn’t bother to answer her, so she
>   gave her best guess. “I think he’s about three months old.” A thought
>   occurred to her, and she asked, “Where is his mother?”
>
> “I don’t know. The child was brought to me by a house elf who’d been
>   silenced.”
>
> A shiver ran down Ginny’s spine as she wondered what that meant. She
>   figured she was better off not knowing. “I suppose you recognized him
>   as a Malfoy right away.”
>
> Draco snorted. “Yes. For generations, Malfoys have used magic to make
>   sure that our recessive traits win out.”